# Calculating determinant and inverse of $A^2$ if $\det(A)$ and $A^{-1}$ are already known

Tags: matrices, determinant, inverse, adjacency-matrix

for a $3\times 3$ matrix (or any $n\times n$), one way to work out $A^{-1}$ is using $$A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(A)}C^{T}$$ where $C^T$ is the cofactor matrix of A.

This can be extended to powers of A:
 $$(A^2)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det(A^2)}C^{T}$$ where $C^T$ here is the cofactor matrix of $A^2$.

I am wondering how, if $A$, $\det(A)$ and $A^{-1}$ are already known, is there a faster way to work out the following:
 $(A^2)^{-1}$, $\frac{1}{\det(A^2)}$ and $C^{T}$?

ie without doing $AA$, $\det(AA)$ etc

Comment: If you already know $A^{-1}$, you get $(A^2)^{-1}$ simply as $(A^{-1})^2$. Further, $\det (A^2) = \det(A)^2$. Hence the cofactor matrix of $A^2$ is simply $(A^{-1})^2 \cdot \det(A)^2$.

Answer (score 3):

**1**
$$ C^T = \det(A) \cdot A^{-1} $$
**2**
$$ \det(A^n) = \det(A)^n $$
**3**
$$ A^{-n} = (A^{n})^{-1} = (A^{-1})^{n} $$